# How to take f(x) as user input and make it work like formula using java code?

Tags: java

I am new to coding! If you find this question silly then I beg your pardon at the beginning! 
I was trying to solve Bisection Method using java. And I successfully did it!
I took user input for **initial guess 'a' and 'b'**! In my code I created a method that stores the **"f(x) = x^3 - x - 1"** and when I call this method it solves the bisection method as per my given instructions.

- The problem is I want to take the f(x) from user and use it like a
  formula.
- I tried to take f(x) as String once but then what next? How can I
  form it into a formula?
- Another problem is I cannot use '^' sign as power, I am currently using Math.pow(x,pow); Is there any way to make it('^') work as
  power?
- If user gives input "3x^2 - 2x - 6", how am I supposed to make the
  program realize that the given equation indicates (assuming x = 4)
  "3*4^2 - 2*4 - 6", **Not** "34^2 - 24 - 6" !

I went through many answers but they couldn't satisfy me! I am adding my program below, if anyone can check kindly!

//Bisection Method

```
package numericalMethods;

import java.util.*;

public class BisectionMethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        double a, b, c;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter value of a : ");
        a = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter value of b : ");
        b = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter maximum iteration : ");
        c = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println();



        if ((f(a) < 0 && f(b) > 0) || (f(a) > 0 && f(b) < 0)) {

            for(int i = 1; i <= c; i++){

                System.out.println("*** For iteration " + i + " ***");
                System.out.println("a is a = " + a + " and b is b = " + b);
                System.out.println("So f(a) is f(a) = " + f(a) + " and " + "f(b) is f(b) = " + f(b));

                //declaration and calculation of root variable
                double x = (a+b)/2;

                System.out.println("For iteration " + i + " root is x = " + x);
                System.out.println("And f(x) is f(x) = " + f(x));
                System.out.println("Here f(a)*f(x) = " + (f(a) * f(x)) );

                //Condition for assignment of the value of root x!
                if(f(a)*f(x) < 0){
                    b = x;
                    System.out.println("As f(a)*f(x) < 0, we assign value of x to b.");
                    System.out.println("So now a and b are respectively, a = "+ a + " and b = " + b);
                    System.out.println();
                }else if (f(a)*f(x) >0) {
                    a = x;
                    System.out.println("As f(a)*f(x) > 0, we assign value of x to a.");
                    System.out.println("Now a and b are respectively, a = "+ a + " and b = " + b);
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println("The condition was not fullfilled!");
        }


    }

    //declares function
    public static double f(double x){
        return ((x*x*x)-x-4);

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to know about compilers.

Comment: This is not easy as you need a compiler which is not part of the JRE. Perhaps have a look at jshell?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! @Johannes 
And I went through the answer you mentioned but I found it really hard to understand in many part. Anyway I am working on it. Hope I will get the points soon! :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :) @Thorbjørn

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ScriptEngineManager to evaluate mathematical expressions using the javascript engine.

ofc. you would need to replace "x" with it's substitute first:

```
String formula = "x/2 + x";
Integer X = 6;

ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine eng = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

System.out.println(eng.eval(formula.replace("x", X)));
```

But your question looks like "Homework", so i doubt this solution would be acceptable.

Comment: Thank You So Very Much! 
Your answer somehow helped me! @dognose